# Ruby program ARGV error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a Ruby program:

```
k = ARGV[0]
j = ARGV[1]

def random_tuple(length)
  letters_and_numbers = "0123456789"
  answer = ""
  length.times { |i| answer << letters_and_numbers[rand(10)] }
  answer
end

j.times { |i|  Product.create number:random_tuple(8) }
```

The code takes a argument and generate that mcuh random number but I am getting an error, can anyone suggest where I am wrong.

Comment: I need to see how `Product` looks like?

Comment: Include what error you’re getting in your question, don’t expect us to run your code to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got same error few days back in one of my script . You have to convert ARGV[1] to integer to use it with times method . use j.to_i and it will work.